# In Parsec, Fixing a broken token before a parser fails

Tags: haskell, parsec, parser-combinators

**Background**:

I am using a combination of Alex and Parsec to parse an indentation sensitive language.  An line more indented then the one above it my either be data for that line, or a continuation of the commands on that line.  Alex has no way to know for sure so it simply returns a `Block{...}` token.

The parser knows when a data block is expected and passes the data into the Abstract Syntax Tree to be used by the interpreter.

The problem arises when the parser encounters a `Block` token when it wanted something else.  I have a function that will convert a block token into a list of `Tokens` called `lex_block` but I cannot seem to apply it to the right place in the input stream.

**Question:**

Given a parser combinator that which fails at some token in the input stream, is there a way to modify the token that caused the failure and either continue evaluating the new input stream or at least to try again?

I would like to write a function `retry` as follows:

```
> retry :: (s -> Maybe s) -> ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m a
```

`retry f p` acts like parser `p`, except that if `p` fails the function `f` is used to alter the input stream at the point `p` failed and `p` is retried. When `f` returns `Nothing` the failure is passed on.

I have tried to write this using `getInput`, `setInput` and `try`, but I cannot figure out how to get the input stream at the point the parser combinator failed rather then the point that it started.  I think that if I could discover a way to be told where the failure happened in the input stream I could make this work.

Comment: As I recall, both Haskell (GHC) and Python's indentation sensitive lexers don't send blocks as a unit, but instead give special tokens marking their beginning, new lines, and end (for Haskell, "implicit" `{` `;` and `}` tokens). Is there some reason this wouldn't work well for you? (I guess it would be a problem if the two subformats lexed completely differently.)

Comment: Come to think of it, even if the lexers *are* different you might solve it by letting the lexer *first* give a token telling that a block starts, and then the parser gives a signal back telling which format to keep lexing. (BTW Haskell also has some backsignalling from parser to lexer, because implicit `}`s are sometimes inserted by parser request.)

Comment: In my case an indented block is either the rest of a multi line statement, or a string literal delineated by the end of the indentation.  The lexer doesn't know which case it might be so just returns `Block String` as the token.  I want to catch the "unexpected Block '...' expecting x " and rerun x with the lexed block I just cannot figure out how to catch the parser at the point it actually is about to fail.

Comment: I am pretty sure my second suggestion *should* work for this - basically get Parsec to tell when it wants a data block *before* Alex has parsed anything beyond the initial indentation. However I am not proficient with Alex or the more advanced Parsec interface, so I don't really know *how* to send the information back to Alex at the right point.